# Pull out scaling factor from a denominator

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

How do I force mathematica to display the below expression as a sum `a+b` with a scaling factor of `1/r`.

(a+b)/r

I would like Mathematica to display   (1/r) (a+b), ie. I want it to show 1/r as a scaling factor.

currently,  it shows (a+b)/r   , with r as a common denominator.

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Any code you would like to share ?

Comment: ((a+b)/r)[[2]] ?

Comment: Algohi, try `((2 + x)/7)[[2]]`

Comment: `Coefficient[(a + b)/r, a + b]`?

Comment: @DavidCarraher In this case use Hold[((2 + x)/7)][[1, 2]]

Comment: Algohi, That seems to be a general solution to the problem.

Comment: Please provide wider context. Do you want further terms behave similar, like 1/r^2? I'm asking to not give an answer which will not be useful at the end.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, that's exactly what I am intending to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something close to what you want

```
expr = (a + b)/r;
expr Denominator[expr] HoldForm[1/Denominator[expr] // Evaluate]
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

```
expr = (a + b)/r
1/Denominator[expr]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]